# Same IP address, Different subnet

Tags: networking, subnet

Simple query. Just wondering, if I had one computer

```
 PC-1
 IP:      192.168.1.2/24
```

and

```
PC-2
IP:      192.168.1.2/25
```

Can I ping PC-2 from PC-1 and vice-versa?

Comment: No, because it's a duplicate IP address. They still overlap each other even if you're using a different subnet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Even though the CIDR block notation is different, you can't have two nodes on the same network with the same IP address. In fact, your two subnets overlap.

192.168.1.0/24 has a mask of 255.255.255.0 - CIDR address space of 192.168.1.0-255
192.168.1.0/25 has a netmask of 255.255.255.128 - CIDR address space of 192.168.1.0-127

As you can see, both subnets contain the same address space.